# C# Comparing if two lists have the same order of items (alphabetical)

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm facing a huge problem with comparing two lists. I just made copy of my first list and I tried to sort it. The problem is, I want to compare my original list and sorted one to see if they have same alphabetical order. I hope I provided enough information for my problem.

Thanks in advance

```
public void VerifyDataPrijave(string username)
    {
        
        List<string> listaTekstova = new List<string>(); //initializing new, empty List
        
        
        var kartice = Repo.Kartice.CreateAdapter<Unknown>(false).Find(".//div[class='_63fz removableItem _95l5']");
        foreach (var kartica in kartice) {
            var slika = kartica.Find(".//tag[tagname='img']")[0];
            var ime = slika.Find("following-sibling::div")[0];
            string text = ime.GetAttributeValue("InnerText").ToString(); //loop through profile cards and getting Names as InnerText in variable text
                            
            listaTekstova.Add(text); //adding those "texts" I just found to an empty list initialized before
            
            List<string> novaListaTekstova =  new List<string>(listaTekstova); //clone (copy) of the very first one list
            novaListaTekstova.Sort(); //sorting that list alphabetically (I suppose, not sure)
            

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have not asked a question, nor explained how the posted code relates to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, I  mentioned my problem and it's about comparing my original list and sorted one to see if they have same alphabetical order. Read my question again please.

Comment: "Mentioned my problem" <> "asked a question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0) to compare to IEnumerables. In your case you can do something like this once all sorting has been done:

```
var isEqual = novaListaTekstova.SequenceEqual(listaTekstova);
```

Comment: Do I need any kind of intersection, because order matters in my case? I'm afraid if this is gonna check only if two lists are having same sequences, but their order does not matter. Thank you.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. Are you simply trying to check both lists are sorted alphabetically or that both lists have the same order?

Comment: @disee97 `SequenceEqual()` checks that for each element at index `i`, the values are the same in both sequences. Order matters. "A, B, C" would not match "A, C, B".